# Dashed line for tabular in memoir class with polyglossia

Tags: tables, longtable, polyglossia, arydshln

I keep getting error when using `arydshln` package with my setup below.

Error: `Undefined control sequence. ^^I\hdashline`

when i remove the package and the \hdashline it works, but i need to use dashed line.

MEW:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{arydshln} %<-------------------- Generates error

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\englishfonttt{Inconsolata}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}

\DisemulatePackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\begin{document}
  \begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\centering
\small  
\begin{longtable}{lll}      
    \caption{table}
    \label{table:sum}\\
    \toprule[\heavyrulewidth]
    1. & 2 &   3 \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\hdashline % <------------------- Generates error
    \endfirsthead           
    ex1& ex 2 & ex3 \\  
    \bottomrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Any help appreciated.